# Keep accordion open after reload or postback

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I've been looking at examples and nothing seems to work. Right now I have a button group, where each button serves as a separate category. Once the button is clicked, it will show an accordion and within the accordion there will be forms. For testing purposes, I only have one form right now.

The problem I'm running into is that once I click the submit button, the page completely reloads and once the page is returned everything is closed. I've tried using updatePanel and have had zero luck.

Basically, I want everything to remain open after the reload that was open before the reload.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager id="script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="panel1" runat="server">


 <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width:100%; ">

@* Bucket Group 1 *@




<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formButton1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; border-color:darkgrey; color:black;"><p>Bucket </p>  <text style="font-size:80%;"> Bucket1</text></button>

    @* Overall form for Monitoring *@
    <form asp-controller="test" method="post" role="form" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to carry out this action?');" id="form1" style="display:none;">
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

            @* Form 1 *@



            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                            Test1
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <p> This script will return a value.</p>
                            </div>

                            @Html.DropDownList("Envs", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Envs))), "Select Enivronment", new { @class = "form-control" })


                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            @* Space to display output *@

                            <h5>Output: </h5>
                            <div>
                                <textarea cols="20" rows="2" class="form-control" style="color:cadetblue;font-weight:bold;">  @ViewBag.serviceResponse   </textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            @* Form 2 *@


        </div>
    </form>
</div>


@* Bucket Group 2 *@

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formButton2" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; border-color:darkgrey; color:black;"><p>Test2</p> <text style="font-size:80%">Test 2</text></button>
    <form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none;">
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

            <div class="card" id="get">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">

                        <p> Test2.</p>

                    </h5>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

    </div>





 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript functions to open when buttons are clicked.

```
$("#formButton1").click(function () {
    $("#form1").toggle();

});


// Write your JavaScript code.
// Write your Javascript code.
$("#formButton2").click(function () {
    $("#form2").toggle();

});
```

Comment: store it in local storage.

Comment: @DanielA.White I looked at examples online and to be honest I'm a little confused at how to store it in local storage

Comment: Basically, you have to persist the state and then restore it. There's nothing built in that does this for you; you're on your own. As others have said, you can persist the state with something like localStorage. You might also want to take a look at the History API.

Comment: localStorage is literally just a dictionary. It's just about as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Don't reload the page (add a click handler to submit form data without using the built-in HTML submit)
- Use local storage to store the state of which accordion section was open and initializing the page with the same section open